# Python Pandas read_csv dtype fails to covert "string" to "float64"

Tags: python, pandas, slash

I have a csv file with header = "col1" and 5 values

```
col1
398
5432
5986
8109
/N
```

I intended to set this as a numeric col in pandas so i wrote

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(r'\test1.csv', dtype = {'col1': 'float64'})
```

but error message
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '/N'

Above code works fine without the slash and last row will turn into "Nan". But without changing my original data value, is there any way to suppress the "slash" and make the code run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> data = pd.read_csv(r'\test1.csv', dtype = {'col1': 'float64'}, na_values=[r'/N'])

According to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), the na_values parameter is a list-like structure of strings that can be recognised as NaN.

Answer (score 1):

Try with error_bad_lines=False:

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'\test1.csv', dtype = {'col1': 'float64'}, on_bad_lines='skip')
```

Comment: 'TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines''

Comment: @AaronBramson it is now `on_bad_lines='skip'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `converters`, use `errors='coerce'` to convert to `NaN`:

```
def convert_float(val):
    return pd.to_numeric(val, errors='coerce')

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', converters={'col1': convert_float})
print(df)

     col1
0   398.0
1  5432.0
2  5986.0
3  8109.0
4     NaN
```